# How to fix 'Unexpected token operator' error from UglifyJs?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

In my Angular app, I run this command:

`> ng build --prod --aot --env=staging`

and that outputs:

```
ERROR in vendor.0625f773941bc83e6748.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token operator «*», expected punc «(» [vendor.0625f773941bc83e6748.bundle.js:69512,51]
```

I have narrowed the error down to a npm package I recently installed, [web-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-request).

In the npm-installed `index.js` file, there are a few functions like the following:

```
function get(uri, options) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { return yield create(uri, Object.assign({}, options, { method: 'GET' })).response; });
}
```

And Uglify must not like the `function*`. Given that this `index.js` isn't a part of the source code of the npm package, how can I fix this error?

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of angular cli are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install angular cli 1.5 and change your tsconfig.json target to "es6", perhaps this is a feature only supported by es6?

Comment: I did not need to change my target to es6, but installing `@angular/cli` seems to have fixed it. Thanks!